# Projects using py.test

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I am looking for (list of) projects that use py.test.

I am new to testing, and want to use py.test. I need examples from projects, so i can use py.test extensively. The documentation is good for py.test but is too fragmented to get a good grasp. I have a vague idea of how it works. I saw the py.test video(3hrs) from pycon. But need some working examples in projects.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but we use nose ( http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/0.11.2/ ) at work and find it and the documentation quite helpful.

Comment: I share your feelings about fragmented documentation

Answer (score 3):

There is MoinMoin, Pida, PyPy and a host of other projects using py.test.  In terms of examples you might also look into py.test's own test suite which naturally uses a lot of its features.  Checkout http://bitbucket.org/hpk42/py-trunk and the "testing" sub directory and maybe file an issue on the tracker that you want to see more documented examples on the web page :)

**update:** these days there are some companies and projects listed which use py.test, see

http://pytest.org/latest/projects.html#projects